# Laravel - Model Truncation failing

Tags: laravel-9

I have a model that I'm trying to enable truncating for, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I set up a clean install of Laravel 9 and have attempted to use 3 different ways to truncate.

The first way uses the `Foo::truncate()` method, as [suggested in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#deleting-models), which works in Tinker but not from my `FoosController`. I then tried using the `Foo::query()->truncate()` method, which is similarly ineffective. Lastly, I also tried using `DB::table('foos')->truncate()` which also, frustratingly, doesn't seem to work.

Other model operations seem to work. Is there anything I'm missing here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```php
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::statement("TRUNCATE TABLE foos");
```